# How to store list of countries in Java

Tags: java

I need a Java structure which can store list of all countries. Which Java data structure will you recommend?

Comment: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/I18N/Getalistofcountrynames.htm

Comment: It depends a great deal on the purpose for which you need that list of countries.

Answer (score 2):

You may use `Set` collection implementations like `HashSet` which avoids duplicates (if just names). If you want to keep country code and name, then may be `Map` collection.

Answer (score 2):

Are you going to iterate over the collection?
If so, java.util.ArrayList.

Are you going to use it to do some kind of look up?  Like a 'does this exist' scenario?
If so, java.util.HashSet

Do you need to attach additional information to each country?
If so, java.util.HashMap

Do you need a lookup and an ordered iteration?
If so, java.util.TreeSet.

There's also concurrency to be concerned about, but I didn't see any mention of it, so I'll leave off those guys.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a HashSet which provides both the uniqueness of elements in a set and the constant time of key search.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `Dictionary<k,v>` , I recommend it

Comment: Dictonary in Java is not encouragable. HashMap is the way to go.

Comment: And what are the key and values?

Comment: you may make the country code as a the key like "US","CA" and the value country name

Answer (score 0):

I think a HashSet should be suitable so long as you don't expect to have duplicates. HashSets provide constant time lookup which will speed up searches. You can consider other Thread-safe variants like Collections.SynchronizedSet or CopyOnWriteArrayList if you expect the data structure to be accessed and modified by multiple threads. You'll need to provide more details on the use case to narrow down your options

Answer (score 0):

I've done very similar thing recently as I have a list of languages in my app. I just use an Enum to do that. List of countries is fairly stable, so you shouldn't need to recompile this class to often;)